# PHP not exiting while loop

Tags: php

I am trying to compare cell 0 of every row to the string returned by the browser language. Ex. browser language is "en" matches "en" on row 3. $row_num = 3. My page is not loading which leads me to believe the while statement is infinitely looped.

php

```
$i = 0;
    while ($i <= mysql_num_rows($lang_head_foot)-1) {
      if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2) == mysql_result($lang_head_foot, $i, 0)) {
      $row_num = $i;
    }
}
setcookie('dbs_lang', $row_num, time() + 60*60*24*365*10);
```

Comment: Use mysqli or PDO, mysql is depraced.. *your loop is never ending in case its started..

Comment: mysql is not deprecated but discouraged. Anyway, don’t use it.

Comment: ^ This - and it doesn't exist because you set `$i` to 0, and then never do anything with it, so it'll always be less than or equal to 0.

Comment: mysql_num_rows doesn't change as you fetch data. there'll always be X rows in the result set. As well, why are you simply not doing `where lang = 'en'` or whatever in your query? doing client-side filtering is almost always a sign of bad design, especially for simple string comparisons.

Answer (score 6):

You need to increment your loop counter:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i <= mysql_num_rows($lang_head_foot)-1) {
  if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2) == mysql_result($lang_head_foot, $i, 0)) {
      $row_num = $i++; // <-- increment loop counter
  }
}
```

Comment: It should also be noted that this loop will call `mysql_num_rows` for EVERY SINGLE iteration. Use a variable instead.

Comment: I knew it was something stupid like this. Thank you.

Comment: -1 for not suggesting a better structure of the code.

Comment: +1 for answering the question :3

Comment: @JvdBerg: come on, the purpose of this forum is not to be the fastest with an answer, but to help newbies to write better code. And it is obvious that the structure you use is confusing. A `for` loop is clearly easier to understand for this problem. In short: you encourage bad code instead of offering a cleaner solution as the answer Dan gave for example.

Comment: @arkascha: the question was: `PHP not exiting while loop`. I answered that. If I needed to cleanup every peace of code that comes along, the days of 24 hours where to short.

Comment: @JvdBerg: you need 24 hours to write a little `for` loop?

Comment: @arkascha: please read my comment

Comment: tbh I agree with @arkascha here. SO is not / should not be about giving the fastest answer possible just for some quick rep without fixing or at least mention other problems OP has.

Comment: Imho, JvdBerg explains why the OP's code wasn't working and offers a solution.  @Barzilay offers a better approach, but fails to explain to the OP what they were doing wrong.  Neither answer is perfect, but both together come closer.

Answer (score 3):

use a for loop instead:

```
for($i=0; $i <= mysql_num_rows($lang_head_foot)-1; $i++) {
    if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2) == mysql_result($lang_head_foot, $i, 0))
    {
      $row_num = $i;
    }
}
setcookie('dbs_lang', $row_num, time() + 60*60*24*365*10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be incrementing $i in the while loop so that you exit the while after you've checked all the rows? And perhaps a for loop would be a better choice than a while loop in this case.